# Linear regression with numpy, python, matplotlib. Want prediction results in pandas dataframe, but 1 numpy list given

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I am using linear regression to generate a standard curve to generate results from data measurements. I have gotten the linear regression to work and to plot nicely, however I cannot get my prediction results to be organized into a dataframe. I have tried all sorts of different things to try to separate the long array of prediction results that I get back (the results dataFrame below), but I can't seem to get it:

I'm starting from these 2 data frames:

[image: standards df]

[image: sampleareas df]

And here is what I have so far: Looping through the metals in the standards dataframe, creating a linear regression, and then trying to apply the linear regression results (slope, y-int) to data values in the sampleareas dataframe. Appening them to an empty array called 'ppt', and then converting ppt to a dataframe once out of the forloop.

```
 i=1
 intercepts=[]
 cols=['Metal','Sample','PPT']
 ppt=[]

for metal in standards.iloc[1:6,0:3]:
     i=i+1
     y=np.array(standards[metal].dropna().values, dtype=float)
     x=np.array(standards['ppt1'].dropna().index.values, dtype=float)
     slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err =sp.linregress(x,y)
     xf = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),100)
     xf1 = xf.copy()
     yf = (slope*xf)+intercept
     print(metal,'\n', 'slope =',slope, '\n','intercept =', intercept, '\n' 'r = ', r_value, 
  '\n', 'p = ', p_value, '\n', 's = ', std_err)

'''Create dataframe of prediction results'''

    for j in sampleareas.iloc[:,i]:
        sample=sampleareas['sample']
        areas=ppt.append([metal,sample,(sampleareas[metal] - intercept) / slope])

'''Graph Standard Curves'''

    f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.plot(xf1, yf,label='Linear fit', lw=3)
    standards[metal].dropna().plot(ax=ax,marker='o', ls='')
    plt.ylabel('Peak Area')
    ax.legend()
print(intercepts)
results=pd.DataFrame(ppt,columns=cols)
```

The graphs look good, but unfortunately what I get back for the results dataframe is:

[image: Results dataframe]

The 'metals' column looks good, but I really would like the 'sample' and 'ppt' columns to include just 1 corresponding sample and prediction result per row, rather than all the samples and prediction results per row. I believe the error is originating in the
`[sampleareas[metal] - intercept) / slope]`  notation, but I do not know how to make it work otherwise.

Any suggestions or help is appreciated. I have attached the beginning sequence of code below as well.

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
standards = pd.read_csv('standards.csv')
standards.set_index('standard', inplace=True)
sampleareas=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: you aren't using `j` in your inner-loop, is that on purpose? would `sample=sampleareas.iloc[j]['sample']` help? is `sample` supposed to be a single value or a vector in the inner-loop?

Comment: Well not using j was just the process of trying things out, not exactly on purpose. I tried putting j in with .iloc as you recommended, and it didn't like the syntax. `'sample'` is supposed to be a moving vector for each loop of the forloop, but just a single value each time, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that worked out:

```
intercepts=[]
cols=['Metal','Sample','PPT']
ppt=[]
standards['ppt1']=standards.index
for metal in standards.iloc[1:5,3:9]:  
     y=np.array(standards[metal].dropna().values, dtype=float)
     x=np.array(standards['ppt1'].dropna().index.values, dtype=float)
     slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err =sp.linregress(x,y)
     xf = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),100)
     xf1 = xf.copy()
     yf = (slope*xf)+intercept
    print(metal,'\n', 'slope =',slope, '\n','intercept =', intercept, '\n' 'r = ', r_value, '\n', 'p = ', p_value, '\n', 's = ', std_err)

'''Create dataframe of prediction results'''        
    for index,j in enumerate(sampleareas.loc[:,metal]):
        pred = (j-intercept/slope)
        sample=sampleareas['sample'][index]
        areas=ppt.append([metal,sample,pred])

'''Create a table of intercepts'''
intercepts.append(metal)
intercepts.append(intercept)
intercepts.append(slope)

'''Graph Standard Curves'''
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(xf1, yf,label='Linear fit', lw=2)
standards[metal].dropna().plot(ax=ax,marker='o', ls='')
plt.ylabel('Peak Area')
ax.legend()

print(intercepts)
results=pd.DataFrame(ppt,columns=cols)
```

The enumerate function across the index,j in the nested forloop was the part that was missing from the scheme.

Cheers!